# window overflow in full width page

Tags: overflow, css

I'm developing a website ( portfolio redesign ), and I'm working in full width. But I keep having the same problem and however I'm trying to fix it, it just doesn't work.

I would appreciate if someone could help me out with it, I will paste only the link here because there's to much CSS to paste and HTML markup, but I think by looking in console you can see what's going on in there.

Link: [Website](http://rolandgroza.com/projects/roland/)

The problem it's pretty obvious, you'll see that an horizontal scroll appears and if you scroll the content it's overflowed by nothing, just empty space, maybe about 60px wide I think. I tried adding `padding: 0;`, `margin: 0;` or anything I could think of, but with no success.

I know that adding `overflow: hidden;` would fix it, but I need the overflow there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this , it should work.. tested it with firebug.. hope its cross browser

```
html {
color: #222222;
font-family: sans-serif;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: As I said, I prefer not using `overflow: hidden`, but till now that seems to be the only solution :|

Comment: i dont c anything wrong with `overflow:hidden` .. some element in the page is expanding more than 100%.. so,setting the wrapper to `overflow:hidden` should be a good workaround.. but,i agree - its not the perfect solution..

Answer (score 1):

It might be a few things.

Since you're going full width, everythings set to 100%, right? But on the bottom you have six elements. 100/6 = 16.6666666666667 and so on. It doesn't divide nicely. I see you rounded down to 16.5, but that'll only make 99%. I've never had good luck with factions of percent. Could you ,aybe reduce your bottom nav to 5 elements for an even 20%?

You could also try using a sticky footer and relative positioning, like I did **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/pYp9e/)**.

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">    
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<footer>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
  position: relative;
}

#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  width: 100%    
}

nav li {
  display: block;
  background-color: #222222;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;  
}

footer li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
 }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Indeed, it might be because of many things. I managed to make it better now, but still the problem persists. And yes, the footer is somehow not divided perfectly, but as you can see I changed two of the href tags to 17% so that would make it fit. I thought of making 5 blocks too, maybe I'll end up doing that after all.

Answer (score 0):

In my browser I don't see any horizontal or vertical scroll bar. However, you can try using standard `DOCTYPE`like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-transitional.dtd">
```

and add the following at the beginning of your css:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your window has more than `1366px`, because that's my screen size and the scrollbar it's there. Anyway, I'm already using normalize styles, the http://html5boilerplate.com it's what I'm using for optimizing pretty much anything it needs optimizing.